# Clopen sets in Zariski Topology

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Is it possible for a set to be both open and closed in the Zariski topology over the complex affine or projective space?

Comment: Hint: affine and projective space are irreducible.

Comment: Clopen subset of, which space exactly? In the Zariski topology of an algebraic set like $\{0,1\}$ this is clearly possible. But in an irreducible space...

Comment: thanks, and sorry, im completely new to this field so my understanding is very limited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized the [elemntary] answer, if a set and its complement are closed, then the whole space being the algebraic set of the equation 0=0 can be written as a union (pairwise multiplication) of two sets of equations. however one of them would must be zero in order to recover such a multiplication.